# Keep Livestream Video maximized on second monitor

Tags: video, ultramon

I have two monitors, I work with the first and watch livestreams on the second one. If I maximize the video on the second one and return to work on the first monitor, the video gets minimized again.

What can I do to keep the video maximized while working on the first monitor? I use UltraMon.

Comment: Lifehacker posted an article a while back, and I can confirm that it works. It just involves some modification of the adobe flash dll. so remember to Back It Up!
[link](http://lifehacker.com/5419028/keep-flash-videos-in-full-screen-on-dual-monitors)

Answer (score 0):

Ultramon has no control over the application showing the stream. Most media players will drop full screen when they lose focus. QuickTime (in Mac) has a setting to prevent that, but I’m not sure about Windows.

In any case, Ultramon doesn’t have much to do.